# Doing a IN statement with LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use dictionary inside linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513767/use-dictionary-inside-linq-query)

How can I make a `IN` statement with LINQ ?

**What I have**

```
    var t = from i in emails
            where i.Credencials_Id == agenciaid
            select new
            {
                i.Alias,
                i.Name,
                i.Description,
                i.Comentas,
                i.DateHour,
                i.Imovel_Id,
                i.Email,
                i.EmailCaptador
            };
```

**What I Want (Something like this)**

```
    var t = from i in emails
            where i.Credencials_Id IN (agenciaid)
            select new
            {
                i.Alias,
                i.Name,
                i.Description,
                i.Comentas,
                i.DateHour,
                i.Imovel_Id,
                i.Email,
                i.EmailCaptador
            };

int imovel = Convert.ToInt32(t.First().Imovel_Id);
```

Comment: If you use Linq2Objects: `where agenciaid.Contains(i.Credencials_Id)`, Linq2Sql can encounter a parameter limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using LINQ to Objects you can use this:

```
from i in emails
where agenciaid.Contains(i.Credencials_Id)
select new
{
    i.Alias,
    i.Name,
    i.Description,
    i.Comentas,
    i.DateHour,
    i.Imovel_Id,
    i.Email,
    i.EmailCaptador
};
```

Comment: I got the following error `System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains (System.Object)' which can not be converted to an expression Storage`

Comment: In that case you are not using LINQ to Objects. I mark your question as a duplicate. See the accepted answer of the linked question on how to do it.

Comment: But how can I call the `WhereIN` method in my case ?

Comment: EF supports the contains keyword.  agenciaid needs to be some kind of collection, int[] or List<int> etc...

Comment: TGnat agenciaid is a `ArrayList` but occurs the error that I told above.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos which version of EF are you using?

Comment: @TGnat I'm using EF version 3.5

Comment: @Lucas_Santos Can you use a more strongly typed collection... List<int> for example.