# Why can't I use dictionary["key"] for a where clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5, where-clause

I'm running a simple LINQ query:

```
var user = (from u in context.Users
          where u.Email == dictionary["email"]
          select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I run that, I get this exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

If I use an intermediate step of this, it works fine.

```
String myDictionaryItem = dictionary["email"];

var user = (from u in context.Users
          where u.Email == myDictionaryItem
          select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just seems kind of odd that .Net can't think a little faster to make that connection.

(disclaimer: maybe some typos, I changed some variable names)

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to entity framework: use dictionary in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638859/linq-to-entity-framework-use-dictionary-in-query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linq tries to translate your where clause to SQL and fails because SQL has no dictionaries. Once you give the parser a simple string it is able to produce an SQL statement.

You can make it execute the filter locally, not on the SQL server, **but it would hit performance**:

```
var user= (from u in context.Users select u)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(u=>u.Email == dictionary["email"])
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was ready to upvote you until I saw the second part where you gave the option of running the filter after getting ALL records, I would never even want to mention this option to someone who doesn't fully understand the implications.

Comment: There are only and only two options: Either fetch all the records and have fully-supported bunch of extension methods or define an intermediate variable.

Comment: Tim, the answer is still useful. It gives me the 'why' answer I was looking for plus shows it it's possible but that it's also a bad idea.